# Is asking questions about a particular health dataset on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is asking questions about a particular health dataset on-topic? I know they are on-topic on OpenData.SE, but I am curious to know whether they are allowed in in this Stack Exchange.

Examples:

- [Temperature: data items 676 and 677 both refer to temperature; can both be combined even if they were measured from different or same site](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/4673/43):

  > Concerning the MIMIC II database, Temperature as a variable has 2 occurences for each patient: id 676 and 677 both refer to temperature; the question is whether both are measured from the same site or from different sites, and therefore whether they can legitimately be combined?
- [From which artery the ABP signal was collected?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6939/1652)